# TabLayout Tab select issue

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I have made TabLayout

when I select Tab ..  Text color changing 
But the Previous Selected Tab text color Didn't change

Like [image: here]

here Is My Java code 
which is Fragment

```
public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help,container,false);
        ini();
        pressing();
        return rootview;

    }
    private void ini()
    {
        tabs = (TabLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        setupTabLayout(tabs);

     }
    private void pressing()
    {

        tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                TabViewHolder holder = (TabViewHolder) tab.getTag();
                if (holder == null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "ViewHolder for tab " + tab.getPosition() + " not set");
                } else {
                    tab.setIcon(holder.selectedIconId);
                    Log.e("TAG",tab.getPosition() + " // onTabSelected ");

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                TabViewHolder holder = (TabViewHolder) tab.getTag();
                if (holder == null) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "ViewHolder for tab " + tab.getPosition() + " not set");
                } else {
                    tab.setIcon(holder.unselectedIconId);
                    Log.e("TAG",tab.getPosition() + " // onTabUnselected ");

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                Log.e("TAG",tab.getPosition() + " // onTabReselected ");

            }
        });
    }
    private void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        TabViewHolder homeTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" , R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);
        TabViewHolder inboxTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" ,R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);
        TabViewHolder starTabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" ,R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);
        TabViewHolder star2TabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" ,R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);
        TabViewHolder star3TabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" ,R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);
        TabViewHolder star4TabHolder = new TabViewHolder("Hour service" ,R.drawable.hourservice_one_selected, R.drawable.hourservice_one_unselected);

        final TabLayout.Tab home = tabLayout.newTab()
                .setText(homeTabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(homeTabHolder.unselectedIconId) // set this as first selected
                .setTag(homeTabHolder);

        final TabLayout.Tab inbox = tabLayout.newTab()
                .setText(inboxTabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(inboxTabHolder.unselectedIconId)
                .setTag(inboxTabHolder);

        final TabLayout.Tab star = tabLayout.newTab()
                .setText(starTabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(starTabHolder.unselectedIconId)
                .setTag(starTabHolder);
        final TabLayout.Tab star2 = tabLayout.newTab()
                .setText(star2TabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(star2TabHolder.unselectedIconId)
                .setTag(star2TabHolder);
        final TabLayout.Tab star3 = tabLayout.newTab()
                .setText(star3TabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(star3TabHolder.unselectedIconId)
                .setTag(star3TabHolder);
        final TabLayout.Tab star4 = tabLayout.newTab()
                 .setText(star4TabHolder.text)
                .setIcon(star4TabHolder.unselectedIconId)
                .setTag(star4TabHolder);

        tabLayout.addTab(home,0,false);
        tabLayout.addTab(inbox,1,false);
        tabLayout.addTab(star,2,false);
        tabLayout.addTab(star2,3,false);
        tabLayout.addTab(star3,4,false);
        tabLayout.addTab(star4,5,false);
        tabLayout.setSelected(false);
         // tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white));
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.tabunselected),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white)
        );

    }
    private static class TabViewHolder {
        int selectedIconId, unselectedIconId;
        String text;

        public TabViewHolder(String text,int selectedIconId, int unselectedIconId) {
            this.text = text;
            this.selectedIconId = selectedIconId;
            this.unselectedIconId = unselectedIconId;
        }
    }
}
```

**And here My XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabText"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabContentStart="30dp"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
    app:tabPaddingEnd="5dp"
    app:tabPaddingStart="5dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/tabbackground"


    android:layout_above="@+id/avaiable"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

can anyone Just tell me what`s worng
and why this behaviour

Comment: try it using `app:tabTextColor` and `app:tabSelectedTextColor`

Comment: I used It  Instead Of 
tabLayout.setTabTextColors(
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.tabunselected),
                ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.white)
        );
but the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can inflate custom view

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.icon_tab, null);
    AppCompatTextView tv = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tab);
    ImageView imgTab1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTab);
    imgTab1.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_tab_search);
    imgTab1.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    tv.setText(titles[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(view);
```

Layout icon_tab

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTab"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="12dp"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_notification"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/lblCount"
                android:layout_width="17dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_tab"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="99"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/tab"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:drawablePadding="3dp"
            android:textColor="@color/item_tablayout"
            android:textSize="10sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

// folder res/color/item_tablayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:color="@color/skyblue_button"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by adding a ***TabSelectListener*** to your TabLayout as follows

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(navActiveIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
                tabLayout.setScrollPosition(tab.getPosition(),0f,true); // This is code that solves the problem
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                tab.setIcon(navIcons[tab.getPosition()]);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

The code that actually resolves your problem is on the *onTabSelected* method and its `tabLayout.setScrollPosition(tab.getPosition(),0f,true);`